# Unable to show "Searching" when using select2 (Loading remote data)

Tags: jquery-select2

Refer to https://select2.github.io/examples.html, text "Searching" is shown when the remote data is loading. However, I don't know why "undefined" is shown in my case.

This is the css file.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <select class="js-data-example-ajax form-control" style="width:100%;">
    <option value="select2/select2" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And the setting of ajax call

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "/search/products",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term,
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
          return {
            results: data.items
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      templateResult: formatProduct, 
      templateSelection: formatProductSelection
    });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: is `search/products` definitely returning valid json?

Comment: yes, the search result is shown properly

Comment: I'm having the same issue. While loading, I have a "undefined" shown there. If you remember the solution you found, @tony.0919, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatRepo (repo) {
    if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

    var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
    '<img src="' + repo.owner.avatar_url + '" style="max-width: 100%" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div clas="col-sm-10">' +
    '<div class="clearfix">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-6">' + repo.full_name + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + repo.forks_count + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + repo.stargazers_count + '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    if (repo.description) {
      markup += '<div>' + repo.description + '</div>';
    }

    markup += '</div></div>';

    return markup;
  }

  function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.full_name || repo.text;
  }

  $ajax.select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, params) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
  });
```

complete code which loads repositories in select 2 you can alter this code according to your requirements 
[image]

my select box with multiple select

```
<select id="to_users" name="to_users" class="form-control js-data-example-ajax" multiple="multiple">
                                                        </select>
```

you can format results

```
processResults: function(data, page) {
                    // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                    // alter the remote JSON data
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                        return { id: obj.user_id, text: obj.name };
                    })
                        //results: data
                    };
                },
```

if you are formatting results to select2 behaviour then disable code

```
/*  escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
                return markup;
            }, // let our custom formatter work

            templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```js
function formatRepo(repo) {
  if (repo.value == undefined) {
    repo.value = 'Loading...'
  }
  var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' + repo.value + '</div>'

  return markup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible workaround for the above issue. Feel free to make comments.

Here is the code I've written before, let say the return JSON is `{"items":[{"id":1,"name":"Product1"},{"id":2,"name":"Product2"}]}`

```
var formatProduct = function(data){
   return '<div>'+(data.name)+'</div>';
}
```

I've modified the code as follow and the 'Searching...' text shows again:

```
var formatProduct = function(data){
   return '<div>'+(data.name || data.text)+'</div>';
}
```

In select2.js, **line 798**, when the data is remotely loading

```
this.template(data, option);
```

this.template directs to select2.js **line 1058**

```
Results.prototype.template = function (result, container) {
  var template = this.options.get('templateResult');
  container.innerHTML = template(result);
};
// result is an object indicating whether the data is loading.
// {disabled: true, loading: true, text: "Searching…"}
```

the template here takes the custom parameter 'templateResult' and generate the text, therefore, the custom function must contain `data.text`, otherwise it returns `underfined`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the `formatProduct` function (it has a different name in my code, but it's the same thing). 
Let's say you call formatProduct for templateResult:

```
templateResult: formatProduct
```

In this case you have to check what formatProduct returns, like:

```
function formatProduct(product) {
           return product.name || product.text;
         }
```

In my case I was returning always product.name and the "Searching" text was under product.text, so I had to check to display it when no product was being found yet.